# Rotate Windows form upside down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# application that has an existing WinForm that I now need to display upside down.

The application will be displayed on a touchscreen Windows 7 device. If two people are using the device, one person is viewing it right-side-up while another user will be simultaneously viewing it upside-down. I will need to have one control displayed right-side-up while another control is displayed upside-down, each duplicate forms. Both need to be functional. It is not necessary for the title bar and Windows close, maximize, and minimize to be rotated.

Is there a way to easily rotate this Form and all of its contents without having to rewrite it from scratch?

Comment: An image of the form upside down?  Or just the controls in reverse position.  Things like TextBoxes don't really display in an upside down fashion.

Comment: The entire form needs to be upside down and functional. A will add more information to the original question to clarify the use case...

Comment: Are you talking about inverting the display?

Comment: @Dhawalk Inverting the display is not an option. See my edited question for clarification.

Comment: Winforms is not the ideal platform for touch screen applications, especially with those requirements.  Consider WPF.

Comment: Agree with @LarsTech. winforms is a useless dinosaur. It takes 1 line of XAML to do this in WPF.

Comment: @LarsTech I understand that. It's a legacy application and I would prefer not rewriting in WPF, which is why I ask this question.

Comment: An alternate is add you Winform app in a WPF form that understands the screen flip

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, rotating controls is not directly possible in WinForms.

At least, not if you want them to retain their functionality. It would be relatively simple to draw the control into a bitmap, rotate the bitmap, and then draw that back to the desired location on the form. But you would obviously lose the ability to interact with the controls. They would just be static representatives of their original selves.

But making functional upside-down controls just isn't going to happen. I mean, you could *try* to write a bunch of custom drawing code for owner-drawn controls, but you'll still run into a bunch of bugs, corner cases, and compatibility problems. The Win32 controls that WinForms is based on just don't support this. No big surprise, really, considering they were invented some 20–25 years before anyone thought of computer screens that you could carry around in your pocket and rotate in any direction. There is a good reason that UI technologies like WPF came out around the time that touch screens and tablets did.

There *are* some possibilities that can be explored when it comes to flipping the entire screen, but that's not going to help when you want different controls going different directions. (And I guess it betrays my vantage point as a desktop app guy when I say this, but that just sounds like an incredibly confusing UI.)

If you absolutely have to have this, someone else is going to have to give you another route to hack it, perhaps along the lines of Dhawalk's comment: hosting the WinForms control inside of a WPF app that does provide built-in support for rotated controls. I don't know enough about this to make any concrete suggestions down that path. From a few minutes of searching, it appears that WindowsFormsHost does not actually support rotation transforms, so this may be a non-starter anyway.